# I'm having trouble changing the value in input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, dom-events

Part of the project is as follows:

```
...
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
  error: null
}

const SignInPage = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <h2>Sign In</h2>
      <SignInForm/>
      <SignUpLink/>
    </div>
  )
}

const SignInFormBase = props => {
  const[init,setInit] = useState(INITIAL_STATE);
  const onSubmit = () => {

  }
  const onChange = (event) => {
    setInit({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })    
  }
  const isInvalid = init.password === '' || init.email === '';
  return(
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input
        name='email'
        value={init.email}
        onChange={onChange}
        type='text'
        placeholder='Email Address'
      />
      <input
        ...
      />
      <button disabled={isInvalid} type='submit'>Sign In</button>
      {init.error && <p>{init.error.message}</p>}
    </form>
  )
}

const SignInForm = compose(
  withRouter,
  withFirebase
)(SignInFormBase)
export default SignInPage;
export {SignInForm}
```

The problem is:
When I replace the values ​​in init with setInit in the onChange function, I get the following error.

> Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa) . Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

**Note:** I have the same problem in the password section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You strip part of the code but I assume that you didn't read react hooks documentation good enough. By using hooks you won't get replacement for the `setState` which was previously merging the values. Therefore when you call

```
setInit({
   [event.target.name]: event.target.value
})
```

you will replace whole `init` variable with the new object therefore other field will be pointing to undefined value and react will change component to uncontrolled, then again to controlled when you enter value. If you want to maintain object in state you need to do merging by yourself. Easiest way would be to use object spread as

```
  setInit({
    ...init, // <- spread old state
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  })
```

With this code old state will remain between inputs. I would also suggest you to not infer state property from the field name as later you can easily introduce bug you can create curried global onChange as

```
const onChange = (field) => (event) => {
  setInit({
   ...init,
   [field]: event.target.value
  })
}

return (
  <input onChange={onChange('name')} />
)
```